# How do I set a custom origin for socket.io-client connections?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cors, cross-domain, node-webkit

I want to connect my node.js client (node-webkit) to a socket.io server that I do *not* have direct access to. The server requires a connection to match a certain origin in the request header, but I cannot find a way to change it.

This is what I have:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');

socket = io.connect( url );
```

*To reproduce, the `socket.io` package needs to be installed using npm*

It connects to the server, sends some 'pings' and 'pongs' after which the server terminates the connection (as expected because of the wrong origin).

Note that I cannot change the server, so simply adding an origin to the white-list is no possibility.

## Things I've tried so far

Using `extraHeaders` like this:

```
socket = io.connect( url, {extraHeaders: {origin: url}} )
```

..but that doesn't change the origin. I've tried to edit other/custom headers but the `extraHeaders` option doesn't seem to do anything.

I've also looked into the node `cors` module, but the [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuring-cors) only provides examples on how to set an origin for `express` app requests, not `socket.io`.

And lastly I've simply tried to set the global `origin` variable to the right url, but that isn't picked up by `socket.io`.

Note: To check whether any of these methods work I looked at the 'Network' tab in the DevTools to see the request headers.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, anyone using socket.io-client and having the same problem, you can resolve this by creating a tiny web-extension which is then added to your browser. You of course must add this as an installation condition of your app.

In the content-script and background script, add an intercepting request event handler. The handler can update the origin header value to the current tab source origin or whatever.

1. content-script.js

```
(async () => {
  await browser.runtime.sendMessage({action: "setActiveTabOrigin"})
})();
```

2. background.js

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (params) => {
  if (params.action == "setActiveTabOrigin") {
    window.origin = await browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true})
      .then((tabs) => {
        for (var tab of tabs) {
          if (tab.active) {
            const url = new URL(tab.url)
            return url.origin
          }
        }
    })
  }
});

function rewriteWSHeaders(e) {
 for (var header of e.requestHeaders) {
   if (header.name.toLowerCase() == "origin") {
     if (header.value == "null") {
       console.log("!!! Setting request origin to the active tab url origin : ", window.origin)
       header.value = window.origin
     }
   }
 }
 return {requestHeaders: e.requestHeaders};  
}  

// For the API details, refer to [mozilla's docs][1]
browser.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  rewriteWSHeaders,
  {urls:["ws://<socket.io-server.host>/*"], types:["websocket"]},
  ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]
);
```

Partial web-extension manifest.json :

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<remoteHost>/*"],
      "js": ["content-script.js"],
      "runAt": "document_start"
    }
  ]

  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "tabs"
  ],
```

Other prerequisites not explained but easily looked up

1. This option is only useful when you target a known remote host because the remote host must be added to the 'cors allowed origins' list, passed-in as a python-socket.io constuctor parameter.
2. The web-extension origin must also be passed to this list

```
websock = socketio.AsyncServer(
      async_mode='asgi',
      logger=logger,
      cors_allowed_origins=[extOrigin, <remoteHost>])
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change any thing from client side, it is a server side configuration.

If you have access to there server just add your origin to the **IO Server** origins list or set it to *.

here is a [how to link](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server-origins-value) from **socket.io** [docs](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/).

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that I do not have access to the server. I want to know how to edit the origin header within the client.

Comment: Actually you can not change it within the client, you can not fake your origin that way you are breaking security rules, l prefer you read this article it will help you alot, follow the this link. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: True, modern browsers don't allow users (JS) to set the origin, they set it automatically. But it is possible with node, for example for exxpressjs/cors requests using [this guide](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuring-cors). Thanks anyway!